# Python add new column with repeating value based on two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
Doc Item
1    1
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    2
```

I want to add third column with repeating values that (1) increment by one if there is a change in column "Item" and that also (2) restarts if there is a change in column "Doc"

```
Doc Item  NewCol
 1    1     1
 1    1     1
 1    2     2
 1    3     3
 2    1     1 
 2    2     2
```

What is the best way to achieve this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please supply the code on how you store the DF, it will be easier to help you that way

Comment: @Tamir You can use `pd.read_clipboard` unless it's MulitIndex or having datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) wth custom lambda function with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['NewCol'] = df.groupby('Doc')['Item'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]) + 1
print (df)
   Doc  Item  NewCol
0    1     1       1
1    1     1       1
2    1     2       2
3    1     3       3
4    2     1       1
5    2     2       2
```

If values in `Item` are integers is possible use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['NewCol'] = df.groupby('Doc')['Item'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```